# How to update MySQL table column when another table is updated

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: Product and Review. When enter a review in the review table, I want the Product table to automatically update with (review_count+1) and (stars=avg of all stars). How can I do this?. The two tables are joined by the product_id. How can I do this?

[image: This is the ERD]

Comment: Create a [TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html).

Comment: Can you explain more? I dont know anything about triggers

Comment: Did you read the link? What you need to do is create a trigger that fires on insert action on the first table and then inside that trigger, you can perform the updates to the second table you need to update based on actions on the first table.

Comment: Yes, I read it. Is this correct?
create trigger update_review_count after insert on Review for each row 
update Product
set review_count=review_count+1
where product_id=new.product_id;

Comment: Yes. You can also calculate the count instead of adding 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer if anyone else was wondering. I had to make a trigger that calls two procedures, since I can't make two triggers on the same table. Heres the code:

MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure update_review_count(IN pid INT)
update Product
set review_count=review_count+1
where product_id=pid;$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
create procedure update_stars(IN pid INT)
update Product
set stars=(select avg(stars) from Review where product_id=pid)
where product_id=pid;$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
create trigger review_trigger after insert on Review for each row
begin
    CALL update_review_count(new.product_id);
    CALL update_stars(new.product_id);
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```